# Describe the complex solutions of the equation $(z − 1)^n = z^n$ in standard form.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let n be a positive integer. Describe the complex solutions of the
equation $(z − 1)^n = z^n$ in standard form.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why? What have _you_ tried on the problem so far; what are you stuck on, what do you know about complex numbers?

Comment: i tried z^n= cos(nθ)+isin(nθ), but don't know how can i deal with (z-1)^n

Comment: Hint: $0$ is clearly not a solution, so the equation is equivalent to $$\left(\frac{z - 1}{z}\right)^n = 1.$$

Comment: Also, I am presuming you recall the idea of the $n^{th}$ roots of unity (1)?

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905854

Comment: oh! Thanks! so now i got 1-1/z=cos(2kπ/n)+i*sin(2kπ/n)  for k=0,1,2....n-1 and then solve for z?

Comment: You should only get $n-1$ solutions. Do you see why? Which root of unity do you have to discard?